# With the Lwip TCP stack, what happens if the received message is larger than the buffer?

Tags: c, tcp, buffer-overflow, raspberry-pi-pico, lwip

I have been doing a small tcp project, in C, on a Raspberry Pi Pico, experimenting with the lwIP api. One of the sources of help has been the [pico-sdk-examples](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/blob/master/pico_w/wifi/tcp_server/picow_tcp_server.c).
When the lwip stack receives a message, it summons a callback to a method of the programmer's choice. In the pico examples, *that* method contains the following code for handling the message, which is passed into the callback in a structure known as a [pbuf](https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_0_x/group__pbuf.html). You can chain pbufs together for longer messages.

```
   //state is a protocol control 
   //p is a pbuf

   // Receive the buffer
        const uint16_t buffer_left = BUF_SIZE - state->recv_len; 
        state->recv_len += pbuf_copy_partial(p, state->buffer_recv + state->recv_len,
                                             p->tot_len > buffer_left ? buffer_left : p->tot_len, 0);
        tcp_recved(tpcb, p->tot_len);
```

My question is about the *tcp_recved* component. In the [lwip](https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__tcp__raw.html#gabdac0856a52b5789dc897d4c7137ec44) documentation it says that

> This function should be called by the application when it has processed the data. The purpose is to advertise a larger window when the data has been processed.

If the total_len is greater than the buffer size, and the buffer is filled, why does their code advertise that the tot_len was recved. Will that buffer overflow be lost? Also, why don't we use p->len?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to why we don't use p->len, we use p->tot_len because we may want to read the entire pbuf chain. p->len might just be the first x characters, stored in the first pbuf; p->tot_len is the length of the entire string. However, I still do not know what happens if a message is too large.

Edit: If the message is larger than the buffer then the excess will be lost.